# Pros and cons of long-term domain registrations

Tags: domain-registration

What are the pros and cons for long-term domain registrations, such as 5 or 10 years?

One benefit I can think of is locking-in the domain price. I can't really think of any cons (beyond just not using the domain), especially since transferring between registrars is so easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pros

- lock in price
- don't have to worry about renewing
- some believe it has a positive effect on SEO (it's tiny at best)
- don't have issues transferring to a new registrar due to limitations of transferring near the domain's expiration date

Cons

- higher up front cost/expendature
- if you want to transfer to a new registrar you usually have to pay for another year that you don't need

Answer (score 2):

One more con:  You might forget to renew your registration in 2021; that's a long way out.

Comment: Actually that's a good point... I've almost forgotten about domains that I've held less than a year >_<